# How to enable a table of a B2C tenant using the azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-cli, kql

I tried to enable a table (to be queried with KQL) using the Azure CLI running in gitbash on windows. My intention is to enable the SignIn logs for an AzureB2C tenant.

```bash
az monitor diagnostic-settings create \
--name "SignInLogsSetting" \
--resource "/subscriptions/xxxx9c77-29f3-4b22-ba74-762dae90xxxx/resourceGroups/rg-mycompany-myportal/providers/Microsoft.AADIAM/diagnosticSettings" \
--logs '[{"category": "SignInLogs", "enabled": true}]' \
--workspace "/subscriptions/xxxx9c77-29f3-4b22-ba74-762dae90xxxx/resourcegroups/rg-mycompany-myportal/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/mystuff-dev-loganalytics-ws"
```

I got the following error:

```
usage error: --resource ID | --resource NAME --resource-group NAME --resource-type TYPE [--resource-parent PARENT] [--resource-namespace NAMESPACE]
```

What is wrong with my CLI stament? And how to fix this?

Comment: which version of cli are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs due to the improper resource format of the `resource ID` in
`--resource` parameter.

`--resource` format should be:

```bash
--resource "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/{resourceType}/{resourceName}"
```

*Check and modify below:*

In your CLI code, the resource type is provided as `diagnosticSettings` but resource name is missing here.

And also check when did the `"diagnostic Settings"` introduced in API `AADIAM` version. In few cases, earlier preview versions would not work.

Make sure that `Microsoft.AADIAM` resource provider is properly registered under resource providers in Azure AD B2C.

*Modified CLI code should look like below:*

```bash
az monitor diagnostic-settings create \
--name "SignInLogsSetting" \
--resource "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.AADIAM/tenants/tenantName/resourceName" \
--logs '[{"category": "SignInLogs, "enabled": true}]' \
--workspace "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/newws"
```

*I tried creating a sample diagnostic setting by following the above resource format and was successful as shown.*

```bash
az monitor diagnostic-settings create  \
--name <Name> \
--resource /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/newva \ 
--logs    '[{"category": "AuditEvent","enabled": true}]' \
--metrics '[{"category": "AllMetrics","enabled": true}]' \
--storage-account  /subscriptions/xxxx/resourcegroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/newstrj \
--workspace /subscriptions/xxxx/resourcegroups/xxx/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/newwsjy
```

*Output:*

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/create-diagnostic-settings?tabs=cli) for more relevant information.